# Lattice basis reductions and finding minimal values

Tags: linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry, lattices, cryptography, vector-spaces

While reading several articles about lattice basis reduction I am left with a few questions.

For one, I came across this piece of text

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$. Also let $X>0$ and $X$ is large. Then to compute $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\text{max} (|x|,|y|) \le X$ and such that $|\alpha x + \beta y|$ is minimal we apply the lattice basis reduction to the lattice generated by the columns 
${1 \choose C\alpha}$ and ${0 \choose C\beta}$ for $C$ large enough.

My question is where is the $C$ coming from? When is it large enough? It obviously depends on something... maybe on $X ?$

All hints, examples or explanations are very much welcome.

Comment: crossposted at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427934/basis-reduction-and-continued-fractions

Comment: actually this is a different question...

Comment: Looks very similar to the MSE one